# code everything works until the last line in clsSacarioSymbol method InitalizeClass() obLibrary.addSymbol Me error 424 object required

Tags: excel, vba

'''''

```
  Public obLibrary

  Sub begin()
  Dim obLibrary As Variant
  Set obLibrary = New clsSacarioSymbols
   Call CreateSacarioSymbol
  End Sub
 Sub CreateSacarioSymbol()
  Dim SymbolEditor  As Worksheet
  Dim MsoShapes As Shapes
  Dim SacarioGroup As Object
  Dim SacarioGroupShapes As GroupShapes
  Dim Index As Integer
  Set SymbolEditor = Sheets("Symbol Editor")
  Set MsoShapes = SymbolEditor.Shapes

  '...This Block is for testing and replicates Engineer input to SymbolEditor
  ThisShape As Variant
  For Each ThisShape In SymbolEditor.Shapes
    ThisShape.Delete
  Next ThisShape
  SymbolEditor.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 310.5, 30.75, 129, 99).Select
  SymbolEditor.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 285.75, 99, 174, 61.5).Select
  '....End Testing Block

  MsoShapes.SelectAll
  If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
    Set SacarioGroup = Selection.Group
    Set SacarioGroupShapes = SacarioGroup.ShapeRange.GroupItems
    Dim SacarioSymbol As New clsSacarioSymbol
    obLibrary.InitalizeClass SacarioGroupShapes
  End If

  End Sub

  Class SacarioSymbol "Definition"
  Private Sub class_initialize()
    ' MsgBox "Symbol Class Here"
  End Sub
  Public Sub InitalizeClass(SacarioSymbol As GroupShapes)
    Dim obfrmGetSymbolName As New frmGetSymbolName
    obfrmGetSymbolName.Show    
    SymbolName = obfrmGetSymbolName.GetSymbolName
    **obLibrary.addSymbol Me**
  End Sub
  Class SacarioSymbol "End Definition"
  Class SacarioSymbols "Definition"
  Private SacarioSymbolLibrary
  Private Sub class_initialize()
    MsgBox "Sacario Library here"
    Dim SacarioSymbol As Collection
  End Sub
  Public Sub addSymbol(symbol As Variant)
     SacarioSymbolLibrary.add symbol
  End Sub
```

As I step through the above code all works well until I get the class method clsSacarioSymbol method obLibrary.addSymbol Me I get error 424 Object required I inspect the "Me" object and it contains the correct object
Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: `objLibrary` is not in scope inside `InitializeClass`and that’s what the error is telling you

Comment: even though the objLibrary is a global scope? it is defined as global in Main()

Comment: But then you declare another variable of the same name in `begin`, and it's this version you assign a value to: as soon as `begin` ends, that assigned variable goes out of scope though, and the Global `obLibrary` remains unassigned.  Maybe review this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility for an overview of how scope works in VBA.

Comment: It looks like you've posted a few snippets and then changed things, so it's hard to make sense of what you've got. One thing though that stands out - top of class SacarioSymbols change Private SacarioSymbolLibrary to Private SacarioSymbolLibrary as Collection, and  in class_initialize change Dim SacarioSymbol As Collection to Set SacarioSymbolLibrary = New Collection. But where did what you had come from...